# ASP.NET 4 MVC Decimal Overflow with Fluent NHibernate and SQL Server 2008 RC2

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The following problem is running on a web API application in ASP.NET MVC 4 connected in an [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008) R2 by Fluent [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate).

So I have this form that can store a *decimal* number that can hold a value to 15 integers and 14 decimals places. The database column is defined as `decimal(29,14)` so as the mapped property `Map((x) => x.Factor).Column("FACTOR").Precision(29).Scale(14).Not.Nullable()`.

The data of that field should hold any value in this mask `999999999999999.99999999999999`, but it does't. That number causes an *OverflowException*. I believe that is because of the number limitation, described in its reference: [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) and [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

I really don't understand this notation, `-7.9x1028 to 7.9x1028` (from the C# reference) or `-10^38 +1 to 10^38 -1` (from the SQL Server reference), but I think that what limits the number are the SQL Server decimals, because the error is on the Transaction commit action. The ViewModel shows the right number.

What precision/scale do I need to set on the table column in order to accept the application value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I really don't understand this notation, `-7.9x1028 to 7.9x1028` (from the C# reference)

I prefer the explanation in *[Decimal Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)* (MSDN).

> The binary representation of a Decimal value consists of a 1-bit sign,
>   a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the
>   96-bit integer and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction.
>   The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent
>   ranging from 0 to 28. Therefore, the binary representation of a
>   Decimal value the form, ((-2<sup>96</sup> to 2<sup>96</sup>) / 10<sup>(0 to 28)</sup>), where -(2<sup>96</sup>-1)
>   is equal to MinValue, and 2<sup>96</sup>-1 is equal to MaxValue.

Your decimal number should be written 9 (repeated 29 times) / 10<sup>14</sup>.

The problem is that 9 (repeated 29 times), which is greater than 9x10<sup>28</sup>, is too big to be convertible to 96-bits integer representation (which max value is the 7.9x10<sup>28</sup> of your first definition, which you will retrieve in the remarks of the link above)

In fact, if your try to write

decimal d = 99999999999999999999999999999m;

you will get an error stating "Overflow in constant value computation".

I guess the thing to remember is:
**You can have up to 29 significant digits as long as these significant digits don't form an integer greater than 7.9x10<sup>28</sup>**

It seems that no error is issued when writing

```
decimal d = 999999999999999.99999999999999m ;
```

but some rounding happens. Running some tests on your issue with an [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database, it happens that the number passed as parameter is 1000000000000000.0000000000000 which is (29,13) and is not convertible to (29,14).

Trying to insert 1000000000000000.0000000000000 in a (29,14) column results in "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric."